# Any way to link "checkbox" to an element in another container (only HTML/CSS)

Tags: html, css, html-input

I've this structure where I have to toggle pricing plan between monthly and annually. I have edited the question to provide the `css` with only necessary code-

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #f6f6fe;
}

.cards-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 50px auto;
}

.card {
    flex: 0 0 250px;
    padding: 30px 3vw;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px #b3b5c633;
}

/* SWITCH */
.switch {
 margin: auto 10px;
 display: inline-block;
 width: 45px;
 height: 22px;
 border: none;
 background: linear-gradient(#a3a8f0, #696fdd);
 position: relative;
 vertical-align: middle;
}

.switch .slider {
 margin: 3px;
 display: inline-block;
 height: 16px;
 width: 16px;
 position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
 background: #f5f7ff;
 -webkit-transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0, 0.9, 0.99, 1);
 transition: all 0.2s cubic-bezier(0, 0.9, 0.99, 1);
}
.switch, .switch .slider {
 border-radius: 20px;
}

/* Switch pricing plan */
.switch>input:checked+.slider {
 transform: translateX(23px);
}
```

```html
<small>Annually</small>
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" style="display: none;"></input>     <!-- Checkbox to link -->
  <span class="slider"></span>
 </label>
<small>Monthly</small>

<div class="cards-container">

  <div class="card side-card">
    <h3>Basic</h3>
    <h1 class="monthly" style="display: none">$19.99</h1>    <!-- Element to link to -->
    <h1 class="annually">$199.99</h1>    <!-- Element to link to -->
    <hr>
    <h4>500 GB Storage</h4>
    <hr>
    <h4>2 Users Allowed</h4>
    <hr>
    <h4>Send up to 3 GB</h4>
    <hr>
    <a>Learn More</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to show/hide the corresponding `h1` tag based the state of `checkbox`. **The problem is I don't have to use any sort of script here.**

I tried using `body:has(input:checked) .card .monthly {...}` etc., but as listed on **mdn**, it has no support from browsers.

What else is possible?

Comment: Can you please add your css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can omit the `<label>` in HTML, you can link the checkbox to the corresponding `<h1>` tag.

```css
h1.monthly {
  display: none;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ div.cards-container h1.monthly {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!--<label class="switch">-->
  <input type="checkbox" style="display: block;">     <!-- Checkbox to link -->
  <span class="slider"></span>
<!--</label>-->
<small>Monthly</small>

<div class="cards-container">

  <div class="card side-card">
    <h3>Basic</h3>
    <h1 class="monthly">$19.99</h1>
    <!-- Element to link to -->
    <h1 class="annually">$199.99</h1>
    <!-- Element to link to -->
    <hr>
    <h4>500 GB Storage</h4>
    <hr>
    <h4>2 Users Allowed</h4>
    <hr>
    <h4>Send up to 3 GB</h4>
    <hr>
    <a>Learn More</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: then what about the switch-slider? how would I provide the ````switch```` a container for to hold itself?

Comment: If you need the container, you have to use the script to use the `:has` selector. Or, can you use the switch container just for the slider?

Comment: now I'm  thinking of using ````slider```` as a container for ````slider::before```` which will act as new ````slider````, allowing me to do ````input:checked + .slider:before {....}````. Is it valid?

Comment: I am not really sure what do you want to achieve, but it seems valid. `input:checked + .slider::before`

Comment: your help appreciated!

Comment: I'm glad to help